# Split comma-separated values from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataTable` which is returning a single column result consisting of multiple comma-separated values.

How can I split this column of the `DataTable` based on commas?

Thanks

Comment: String.Split returns an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your desired result?

If you want a `string[]` which contains all values:

```
string[] allValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>(0).Split(','))
    .ToArray();
```

If you just want a `IEnumerable<string[]>` where each element contains all values of a row:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> allRowValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0).Split(','));
```

In either case i use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the `string[]` from the comma separated `string`.

**Edit**: "i am having a List which i want to fill with"

Then you can either cast them to `object` if you really need them as object:

```
List<object> allValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>(0).Split(','))
    .Select(str => (object) str)
    .ToList();
```

or use `List.AddRange` if you already have a list that you want to use:

```
var allValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>(0).Split(','))
    .Select(str => (object) str);

objectList.AddRange(allValues);
```

Comment: i am having a `List<obj>` which i want to fill with

Comment: Why do you want to use `object` if it's actually a string? But you can ccast it to object easily and use `ToList` instead of `ToArray`. Or use `List.AddRange` to add them.

Comment: @roohan: however, i have edited my answer to show you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//fruit dtcolumn values
string fruit = "Apple,Banana,Orange,Strawberry";
string[] split = fruit.Split(',');

foreach (string item in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//datatable should contain result set
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
datatable = YourQuery();

 if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach(int count=0;count < datatable.Rows ; count++ )
  {
    string result = datatable.Rows[count];
    string[] array = result.split(,);
    //do what you want to do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this in c# then try
    table["col1"].ToString().Split(",".ToCharArray())

but if you want to do this in SQL then try this:
http://amerzafar.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/sql-function-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-table/